# How do I cancel a build that is in progress in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Almost unconsciously I hit the keyboard build macro that builds my entire solution. This can happen just as I notice a code change. The build dominates my computer, and I basically have to wait till it finishes. 10 seconds!

How can I cancel a build?

Answer (score 551, accepted):

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> on the keyboard to cancel/stop a build that is currently in progress.

Comment: When I tried it it seemed to depend on which pane within VS had focus  (e.g. Solution Explorer vs Output pane) - but this might not be true

Comment: The break key can be labelled "pause" too

Comment: That's Ctrl + Fn + F6 on your Dell Inspiron, if you have one.

Comment: If your keyboard doesn't have a Pause/Break key, you can go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard then set an extra mapping for the Build.Cancel command.

Comment: "Project cannot cancel build at this time... Try again later." https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-build-is-stuck-cannot-cancel-the-build/329296
Can only kill task in Taskmanager... :(

Answer (score 207):

Go to Visual Studio Build Menu -> cancel build , easy :)

[image]

Comment: You need to turn on Tools -> Settings -> Expert Settings for that to work.

Comment: To go fast, use `Alt + b + a`

Comment: @profimedica I think most people would like to use  the keyboard perhaps Alt + b + a, also works.

Comment: @darmis, The answer marked (Ctrl+Break) did not worked for me. 
I was publishing to Azure, dotnet build finished but the build window continued to display output from the deploying process. I will try Alt + b + a and let you know

Comment: What do you do if "Cancel" doesn't exist and "Alt + b + a" doesn't do anything? And what if you don't have an option for setting "Expert settings"?

Answer (score 20):

This is crude, but it works well. The Visual Studio on one of my projects (I turn MVC view building on to catch markup errors), well, the project becomes unresponsive while building. I can't cancel the build using the keyboard shortcuts.

So I made this batch file that sits on my quick launch task bar.

```
@echo off
echo KILL BILLd
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
   Taskkill /IM aspnet_compiler.exe /F
   timeout 1
)
```

I also made the batch file launch minimized. The build stops and Visual Studio just throws in the error window that there was a problem building.

Comment: throw in MSBuild.exe for non asp_net apps. Xaml locks in live code analysis a lot

Answer (score 13):

If all else fails go to task manager and kill the msbuild task under Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> works, but only if the Build window is active. Also, interrupting the build will sometimes leave a corrupted `.obj` file that will have to be manually deleted in order for the build to proceed.

Comment: Note: In case of VS2017 the shortcut works no matter which window is active.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + End works for me on Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 3

If you are using Mac you can do following

Click Build --> Cancel from the Visual Studio Menu

or

Select Azure App Service Activity window --> Cancel 
it will cancel the publish activity.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. To stop build you can follow:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

The "pause" command was a function button underneath my right shift key, so the below combination of keys did the trick for me.

Ctrl + Fn + Shift

Answer (score 2):

I was hit by an unresponsive build and absolutely nothing would allow me to either kill or cancel the build. Even trying to end the task would trigger a user input window, saying that it could not be ended while the build is still going on (quite ironic because that was precisely the intention, to leave that broken state).

The build was taken care of by MSBuild, so the one way I found is to end its task. When forcing MSBuild.exe to end, VS will wake up and finally see the build as cancelled, allowing you to work again.

Hope this helps someone in the same situation.

Comment: Did this 3 seconds before I read this. I would just add MSBuild to the kill bill script above

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Del to bring up Tasks, then kill VS process (only thing that seems to work)

Answer (score 1):

The build context menu has a *Cancel build* in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Window menu and choose "Web Publish Activity"
There will be a cancel button.
[Cancel button on "Web Publish Activity" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSwBi.png)

Answer (score 1):

For users of Lenovo Thinkpad T470s like me, you can simulate the break key by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, which cancels the build.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a break key on your keyboard, you can change the keyboard shortcut to cancel the build.

Just search `hotkeys` in the search menu. This should take you to `Environment > Keyboard`. From there, search for `Build.Cancel` and you can change it to whatever keyboard shortcut ( eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> ). This is a good keyboard shortcut because it won't conflict with other uses of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> .

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022