# how to stop“build must be stopped before the solution can be closed”

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

The "Build" menu appears as it would if the solution were building, but the `Cancel Build` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>) menu item has no effect.

Trying to close the application prompted as:

> The build must be stopped before the solution can be closed.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Usually it doesn't work immediately because cancelling takes some time, so how long before you try to close the application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do this, look for `msbuild` process(es) and kill them before `devenv`. And make sure vbc really has gone too....

For any further crashes that occur frequently submit them to microsoft so that they can fix the bug...

Hoping it helped....

Comment: `Ctrl+Break` or Go to Visual Studio 2013 Build Menu -> cancel build , that easy. [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997430/how-to-cancel-a-build-that-is-in-progress-in-visual-studio) Hope helps someone.

Comment: I came here because I just got the same problem in VS 2017. It should be noted that the Ctrl+Break command did not work for me in this case. Normally that will cancel the build (same with using the menu feature) but in this particular instance neither worked: it still said it was building even though nothing was happening. Killing the msbuild process(es) fixed the issue and I was able to restart VS.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem and I think I discovered why.

I was drawing *way* outside the boundaries of a bitmap and it was overwriting some memory location that affected Visual Studio.

I added a line of code as a safety while testing that looked for when writing bitmap.Top < 0 or writing > bitmap.Width or > bitmap.Height.

This is supposed to be trapped by Visual Studio but I think it's getting by.

In straight C it's called a wild pointer.