# Error: Visual Studio 2022 "The build must be stopped before the solution can be closed." Disable Bullid option after build

Tags: c#, wcf, build, visual-studio-2022, solution

I have a problem with my Visual Studio 2022 and my Solution.

When I open my Visual Studio 2022, and Build the the entire solution my visual studio disable the button to build and show a message when you try to close : "The build must be stopped before the solution can be closed.".

Before the first Build:

[image]

After first Build:

[image]

[image]

When I try to close:

[image]

I opened VS with Administrator user.

In my solution I have projects dbml, WPF, C# and WCF.

This last one the WCF projects have a problem. Because when I Build another projects the problem don't happened. But when I build the WCF projects the problem happen.

My task manager show this process:

[image]

I tried close one by one to identify the process but i did find.

Only when I force close devenv.exe and open again Visual Studio the build option enable.

Can Someone help me please?

**EDIT:**

This bug was fixed in version 17.2.6 of Visual Studio 2022. Please if you have this error, please update Visual Studio 2022 to the last version.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-doesnt-interrupt-after-build-erro/10038753

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1726--visual-studio-2022-version-1726

Comment: Maybe you can try using Ctrl+Break to stop the build, it will take some time.

Comment: No, this is not a solution for me. Because i can close the visual studio with task manager of windows.

Comment: Killing VS with task manager and restarting the job works, but doesn't conflict with trying Ctrl+Break.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997430/how-do-i-cancel-a-build-that-is-in-progress-in-visual-studio

Comment: @LanHuang, Yes, close and open VS work. But i can't close and open VS every time that I need Build my solution. It is very stressful.

Comment: So have you tried the Ctrl+Break method when you can't close VS? Ctrl+Break is used to cancel/stop a build currently in progress.

Comment: I'm having the same issue now... this started after I updated VS and it said it will remove .Net 5.0, no idea if that messed VS up

Comment: @LanHuang , laptops don't have the 'Break' key. I tried pressing all (Ctrl+Fn+F1-12). Safe to say that it didn't work. I think this is a bug on Microsoft's part in one of their recent patch releases of VS 2022.

Comment: If it helps... I've noticed this happens only for "Build Solution" failures. Doesn't get stuck if you only "Build project" (any project type - library, console app, web app, old websites without csproj).

Comment: @ullfindsmit I try to add again .Net 5.0 and don't work yet. I installed almost all the features of visual studio 2022 and my problem did resolve yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in version 17.2.6 of Visual Studio 2022. Please if you have this error, update Visual Studio 2022 to the last version.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-doesnt-interrupt-after-build-erro/10038753

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1726--visual-studio-2022-version-1726

Comment: Still running into this bug in 17.3.6. All. The. Time.

Comment: I have this bug in vs2022 Version 17.6.4

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Cancel command in the Build menu, which is the same as pressing CTRL+BREAK.

[image: Build menu > Cancel]

Answer (score 0):

Found this bug report in Visual Studio Developer Community Forum.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ASPNET-project-Web-Forms-Build-never/10041947

It says that this bug has been fixed and slated for a future release. It also points to [another bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-doesnt-interrupt-after-build-erro/10038753#T-N10075971) for a workaround.

> Until the fix becomes available, here is a workaround that can be used to unblock this scenario:
>
> 1. Install the [Feature Flags extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulHarrington.FeatureFlagsPreview).
> 2. From Main Menu -> Tools -> Options -> Feature Flags - check the item
>    "Solution.Services.UseLegacy"
> 3. Press Ok and restart Visual Studio.
>
> Another option is to update the value
> [$RootKey$\FeatureFlags\Solution\Services\UseLegacy] from
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.FeatureFlags.pkgdef and run devenv
> /UpdateConfiguration - as described in the discussion above.

Comment: I should add that this workaround worked for me.

Comment: I try this but didn't work for me and worked a littlie bit. This workaround fix build the WCF project, I can build many times after the change, but when I try do right-click in the solution to build entire solution, Visual Studio 2022 crash. Event Viewer log:  `Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at System.String.wcslen(Char*)
   at System.String.CtorCharPtr(Char*)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(IntPtr)
   at System.W`

Comment: hmm ok. VS 2022 17.2.6 has been released, which supposedly resolves this issues. Have a look. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: oh I see you have done that already. cool

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the <kbd>Break</kbd> key for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> method, look for the <kbd>Pause Break</kbd> or <kbd>Pause</kbd> key. If this is accessible by the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>/<kbd>Pause Break</kbd>.